# Where is the Thunderbird Adaptive Junk Mail Log located?

Tags: thunderbird

I have located how to display the Thunderbird Adaptive Junk Mail Log but there is NO Search option available to look through the hundreds of filtered messages for the ones I am concerned about.

I would like to get at the log itself so that I can do searchs.

I am running Thunderbird on Linux and would like to know where that log file is stored.

thanks!
--brock

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, on Linux here, it can be found at:
`~/.thunderbird/default.dxx/junklog.html`